# In Zoness, how do you open the red barriers?

Tags: starfox-zero

Sprinkled throughout the Zoness level are these semitransparent red force field barriers with areas behind them. I have no idea how to open them. The biggest one opens when you hack the panel below it, but all the others are a mystery to me.